# Unity: Collide with Color in specific Layer

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the 2D game I have created the player is a simple geometric figure which may not touch anything with the color black.
Right now all my black objects have complex polygon colliders and creating new objects is just a pain due to this. I have thought of a more unified and performant way to achieve the same result.

This is given:

- Black objects are all on the same layer
- Black objects are only black (#000000) and transparent

What I'd like to do is to drop all colliders on the black objects and check whether or not **anything** below the *players collider*, in the *black layer*, has the color black.

Is there a way to achieve this in Unity? If yes, how could I achieve this?

Example Screenshot: The grey rounded square in the center is the player
[image: Game screenshot, The grey rounded square in the center is the player]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is creating new objects a pain because of the collider? Can't you just add a simpler collider? Like a circle collider?

EDIT: If pixel perfect is what you're looking for try [this tutorial](http://timeshapers.com/2014/05/09/pixel-perfect-collision-in-unity-2d)

Comment: It is a pain because it is important for my game to have kind of pixel perfect collisions. I need to set about 100+ Points for one of those objects and I have lots of them. For the same reason I can not use simpler colliders either. Thats why I'd like to check for the pixel color. That would be pixel perfect and works for all objects at once.
I don't even need "collision", I just need to know if the player somehow touches anything black. As this will kill and reset the player immediately it does not matter if the player slightly walks into the black object.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831242/unity3d-there-is-somthing-like-mesh-collider-to-2d-objects) you can just make a polygon collider fit your thing automatically. Maybe try that?

Comment: Yes, that works fine for straight lines and non antialiased images. It tries for round edges too but I still need to replace all of the points manually because they are not even close to "good".

It's not that I can't do it, but I was hoping for a faster, cheaper and more performant way to do it. I thought that it couldn't be that hard. But maybe I was wrong.

Comment: This tutorial seems to do that. http://timeshapers.com/2014/05/09/pixel-perfect-collision-in-unity-2d/ Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! I think this will help me a lot! Would you create an answer from that so I can accept it?

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help! I changed my original answer to include this.